# A group has an element of order 2 if it has a 2-dim irreducible representation

Tags: group-theory, representation-theory

If $G$ is a finite group, which has a 2-dimensional irreducible representation over $\mathbb C$. Prove that $G$ has an element of order 2.

I don't know how to use the condition of the existence of a 2-dimensional irreducible representation. I try to use the contradiction to prove the proposition but only deduce that $G$ has an odd order and is non-abelian. Thanks for any help.

p.s. I have a course about representation theory for a term so I know most of the result about finite group representation theory. Please don't hesitate to tell me your solution whether it is trivial or not.

Comment: The degree (dimension) of each irreducible representation of a finite group $G$ divides the order of $G$.

Comment: It is very difficult to help with questions like this if you do not provide any information on what results you know already about group theory and representation theory.

Comment: Oh, thanks for KCd. I remember this result! But do you know any other way to prove the order of G cannot be even without the help of Sylow theory?

Comment: If you know the result that the degree of an irreducible representation divides the group order, then you know that the group $G$ has even order. So you just need to prove that a group of even order has an element of order $2$. You don't need Sylow theory for that - it is a standard exercise to prove that directly.

Comment: Cauchy’s theorem can be proved without the Sylow theorems, and the case $p=2$ can be done directly. But why do you want to avoid Sylow theorems?